# Laravel Controller::missingMethod discouraged in 5.0+?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I was coding in 4.2, I'd sometimes use [missingMethod](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#handling-missing-methods) to handle certain situations where I might not know the exact url ahead of time. I noticed today that since 5.0, this part of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers) is gone.

AFAIK, this functioned on Laravel 5.1, but still they removed the documentation on it.

Laravel is always improving the way things are done. Is this functionality discouraged or obsolete now? Surely they didn't remove it from the docs for no reason.

If there is a newer way I should be handling this, can I get a link to the API or snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing methods are used with [Implicit Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers), which have been [officially deprecated since Laravel 5.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L242), but recommendations against using them have been [issued long before that](https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-no-to-implicit-routing). Unlike implicit controllers, explicit route definitions are unambiguous and self-documenting.

I'm not sure how or why you handled unregistered routes via `missingMethod`, but I don't recommended it. I've never been in a situation where I needed to use it. If you need to handle missing route paths you should do that via the `render` method of the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. You can do something along these lines:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

...

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
         // Do whatever you like when a route is not found
         // You can return any response you like
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

You can read more on exception handling in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler)

Comment: I'll agree this is so much cleaner!